# Unable to install yeoman

Tags: node.js, git, yeoman

I'm trying to install yeoman via the terminal using:

```
npm install -g yo
```

I keep receiving this error message( after downloading git) :

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/WayneEnterprise
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing yeoman using `sudo npm install -g yo` as this will run the command as root/Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to install on OSX your best bet is reinstall node.js through homebrew

first off reinstall node.js from homebrew

```
$ brew unlink node
$ brew unlink npm
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
$ brew install node
$ brew doctor
```

then try installing yeoman

```
$ npm i -g yo
```